# How to Convert the date into week

Tags: mysql, sql

Im my Mysql db there is a date field called "completed date " ,its data type is datetime. I need to convert into week format. This should be week ending saturday. this week based date should comes in new column also.Please Provide the query

Comment: Maybe [googling the MySQL documentation](https://www.google.de/search?q=mysql+week&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zGAFVZTzGYHcUqm7gdAC)?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT week("completed date") FROM "myTable";
```

A brief documentation can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: i need to week should  be ending saturday, the week data display as week1       week2      
sun  Mon Tue  wed  Thus Fri sat sun  Mon Tue  wed  Thus Fri sat

Comment: Configure your MySQL or your connection appreciate, and this is what it does (Sunday 1st day of wek). Just RTFM.